# Can Cortex M4 data watchpoint trigger an interrupt without a debugger?

Tags: debugging, cortex-m4, cortex, breakpoint

I am trying to diagnose memory corruption on a Cortex M4 (Kinetis K64). With the debugger (J-Link) attached I can set data watchpoints and the core will stop when a memory address is written.

I want to use this feature for field diagnostics. I set up my watchpoint like this:

```
uint32_t test_variable;
DWT->COMP1 = &test_variable;
DWT->MASK1 = 0; //match all comparator bits, don't ignore any
DWT->FUNCTION1 = (1 << 11)/*DATAVSIZE 1 - match whole word*/
           | (1 << 1) | (1 << 2)/*generate a watchpoint event on write*/;
test_variable = 5; // <<----- CPU stops after this line
```

With the debugger connected I get a breakpoint, the CPU simply stops. When the debugger is not connected nothing happens, the code just runs. I would expect a debug fault or a system reset (like with the `BKPT` instruction without a debugger).

**Is it possible to configure the [DWT](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/ch11s05s01.html) (or perhaps ETM) to generate an interrupt or fault when a watchpoint is encountered without a debugger connected?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked deeper into the documentation and I found out that `DebugMon_Handler` is enabled by:

```
    CoreDebug->DEMCR = CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk /*enable tracing*/ |
                       CoreDebug_DEMCR_MON_EN_Msk /*enable debug interrupt*/;
```

Now I get `DebugMon_Handler` interrupt when the watchpoint is hit.

Comment: I tried this on stm32f103 (which is Cortex-M3 based) using your code and I found that DebugMon won't be called after Power Reset. But it will be called if I do System Reset (i.e. by pulling RESET pin). I find this surprising.

Comment: Filo - User K. Sai Bharadwaj has asked that you look at his related question here: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/619383/3288